# How can I prevent scripts from running inside a directory?

Tags: security, .htaccess

I have a files directory for my image storage in my web root folder, i want to know how to secure that folder. i prevent people from uploading scripts to that folder, i check file extensions, if it is not an image then it will not save to that folder.

but faking extensions are done easily, what happens if someone manage to upload a script to my files directory and access that from the browser

so i need a way to prevent scripts from running inside that folder and only allow images to run.

i know htaccess can do that but i dont know how to set it up. my .htaccess file is like this:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
ForceType application/octet-stream
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  ForceType none
</FilesMatch>
Options All -Indexes
```

but it is not working, i saved a php file in that folder then tried to accessed it from the browser and i can still access it. do you know how to make this work? or if you have more secure approach to this, please tell me.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that it isn't working because you have only **added** an extra handler, you haven't removed the other handlers.

It is easiest to put another .htaccess file in the folder you want to protect (rather than messing with the match directive) that contains:

```
# Fix PHP, you should do matching commands for JSP and ASP, & html
RemoveType application/x-httpd-php php
# .... add the other remove-handler statements here .... #

# Optionally make these equivalent to text files.
# UPDATE: Taken this out as you dont want people to see PHP files at all
#AddType text/html php

# To disable cgi and server side includes & indexes
# You need to check the setup of Apache, some of the file types
# listed should already be handled as CGI (.pl, .py, .sh)
Options -ExecCGI -Includes -Indexes

# Completely block access to PHP files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|phps|html|htm|jsp|asp)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
# Add in any additional types to block
```

That covers PHP and CGI, you should do matching commands for JSP and ASP

UPDATE: Added code to completely block access to PHP files - sorry, thought initially that you simply didn't want them executing. Also note that I've commented out the line that turns PHP files into text files.

Comment: If you wish to keep all your config together in one file, you don't need a clever match directive, just put the config directives above inside a <Directory> block that refers to the dir you wish to configure

Comment: Correct @Cheekysoft. I generally prefer to put .htaccess files in the folder they belong to as it means they will still work even when moved. Still better of course is not to use them at all but to put them in the appropriate Apache configuration file if you have access to them.

Comment: i tried using your code in my .htaccess file inside the files directory but i can still access the .php file.

Comment: Updated to completely block access to a range of file types by extension. Simply adjust the regular expression to suite.